# Create full width nav using svg

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to create [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hD0YC.jpg) nav using an SVG.  I was provided with an SVG however it didn't work out so someone on SO helped me make another.  However now I am unsure how to create the nav using

```
<svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xl="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"
    width="576" height="152" viewbox="0 0 576 152">
  <path transform="translate(10,-185)" d="M 0 189.5 L 39.741071 261.25 L 0 333.125 L 516.63393 332 L 556.375 260 L 516.63393 188 L 0 189.5 Z" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="10" fill="transparent" />
</svg>
```

My current nav looks like

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="completed"><a href="#">Exam</a> <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i></li>
        <li><a href="#">Personal <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Employment</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Appointment</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Record Check</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submit</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

With just a white background.  So it looks close to what the image looks like just minus the SVG shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your SVG needed a little changes to correctly scale itself (with `preserveAspectRatio="none"`) and some more adjusts to your specific layout:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xl="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="576" height="152" viewbox="0 0 576 152" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <path transform="translate(10, -185)" d="M 0 189.5 L 39.741071 261.25 L 0 333.125 L 516.63393 332 L 556.375 260 L 516.63393 188 L 0 189.5 Z" stroke="black" stroke-opacity="0.1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-width="2" fill="white" />
</svg>
```

And here's the CSS using it:

```
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

nav li {
  background: url('path/to/your.svg') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin: 0 -5px;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  font: bold 1rem Sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  padding: 1em 2em;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav li.completed a {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

If you like, here's a [working sample](http://codepen.io/ErickPetru/pen/adzQKp/).

Comment: This is exactly it.  Thanks so much!